# How can I link several CSS files in a single tag in Html?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tags

Assuming I create several CSS files, how can I link them in HTML all in one tag, instead of putting them one by one?

Comment: Combine them into one CSS file, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can link css files from a css file using @import:

For instance if you have a style.css on your index.html then you can reference other css files from it:

```
@import "navigation.css"; /* Relative file */
@import url("navigation.css"); /* Using a url */
```

I hope this is what u are looking for, cheers

Comment: It should be noted that this will result in *extra* HTTP requests, though. One for this file, and another for every import.